# Using float type to represent money amount without arithmetic operations

Tags: java

I understand float/double are bad choices for storing money amounts. When you do some arithmetic operations, you may lose precision.

Is it safe to use float just to represent the amount when arithmetic operations are not performed on that number? For example, mapping amount from API to `float` type.

Comment: No, because you might receive, say, `434324322343432310.13`, which is not a number that can be accurately represented as a float: https://ideone.com/Ms41xI

Comment: I'd always use some scaled integer (storing cents or microcents)

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. Most numbers that "look nice" in base-10 representation, such as 0.1, can not be represented exactly as a binary floating-point number. For example, even when using `double`, the base-10 number 0.1 will be represented as a number that is approximately 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625.

Only numbers where the decimal part can be written as a finite sum of inverse powers of two (1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, and so on) can be represented exactly as a finite binary decimal number (for example: 0.9375, which is the sum of those four numbers). And among those numbers, only the ones that have few enough binary digits can be represented exactly as a floating-point number (at most 24 binary digits for `float` and 53 binary digits for `double`, as per the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)). This is similar to the situation with base-10 numbers; it just happens for more numbers in binary. For example, 1/3 cannot be represented with a finite number of decimals in either base-10 or binary.

However, if you're just storing the number and printing it at some point, you'll probably be fine, because most functions for printing floating-point numbers will round the number off nicely for you.

Comment: that's good explanation. yes, I just store it on DB as an information and represent it via API.

Comment: "Only decimal numbers that can be written as a sum of inverse powers of two ... can be represented exactly" is only true provided there are enough bits of precision to represent that number. A float only has 23 bits to store the significand; these 23 bits encode both the "integer" and "fractional" bits, depending on the exponent.

Comment: @AndyTurner: A good and important point - I expanded on that.

Answer (score 0):

I know a commercial company that uses some kind of double variables in their database to represent money count, and I even know cases where their values differ by 245,20 -> 245,1999999999999999999999 because of that so that should be fine for a learning purpose at least. Just use math.round(value, precision(2)) or whatever math functions / methods for rounding a value java has.